# How may I pass a parameter when navigating in Xamarin.Forms using a static NavigateTo<T> method?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

`NavigateTo<T>()` function located in App.cs

```
public static Task NavigateTo<T>()
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    // do some very simple navigation/lookups
    // basically, just remove the "Model" part of the VM and that is the page
    // "converntion-based" :)
    var viewModelName = typeof(T).Name;
    var pageType = typeof(MainView);
    var pageNamespace = pageType.Namespace;
    var pageAssembly = pageType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var newPageName = viewModelName.Substring(0, viewModelName.Length - "Model".Length);
    var newPageType = pageAssembly.GetType($"{pageNamespace}.{newPageName}");

    var newPage = Activator.CreateInstance(newPageType) as Page;
    var currentPage = ((NavigationPage)Current.MainPage).CurrentPage;
    return currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(newPage);
}
```

ItemListViewModel.cs

```
public ItemListViewModel()
{
    NextPageCommand = new Command(() => App.NavigateTo<DataCaptureViewModel>());
}

public ObservableCollection<Item> LocalItems
{
    get { return localItems; }
    set
    {
        localItems = value;
        Refresh(nameof(LocalItems));
    }
}

public Command NextPageCommand { get; private set; }
```

DataCaptureViewModel.cs

```
public class DataCaptureViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public DataCaptureViewModel()
    {
        //will probably have to set passed in param to SelectedItems
        //once passing in params gets figured out
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

BaseViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Application
{
    public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void Refresh([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnDisappearing()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnAppearing()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I've been developing an Xamarin.Forms application using the MVVM pattern and calling `App.NavigateTo<T>()` when needing to navigate to another page. I've now come to a point where I'd like to pass an `ObservableCollection<Item>` into the page that I'm navigating to. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this using the `NavigateTo<T>()` method. I've asked about in the `WPF` and `C#` chat circles but haven't come to a solution yet. Any ideas?

Please let me know if showing more code is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option-1. Use attached property

***How it works***: In order to pass some navigation parameters - you can store the state for a view (and the view-model) using an attached property. We keep the binding-mode as 'OneWayToSource' - so that once bound - it only updates the ViewModel, not the attached property on View itself;

This way, once `NavigateTo` method explicitly sets the value on the attached property, and we set binding on view; as soon as viewmodel is assigned to view's `BindingContext` - viewmodel gets updated with the attached value due to the binding.

***Steps***:

Create an attached bindable property.

```
public class NavigationContext
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ParamProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Param", typeof(object), typeof(NavigationContext), null, 
                                        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public static object GetParam(BindableObject view)
    {
        return view.GetValue(ParamProperty);
    }

    public static void SetParam(BindableObject view, object value)
    {
        view.SetValue(ParamProperty, value);
    }

    // add more properties if more parameters to be passed..

}
```

Refactor `NavigateTo` to accept a parameter, and assign property value.

```
public static Task NavigateTo<T>(object param = null)
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    // do some very simple navigation/lookups
    // basically, just remove the "Model" part of the VM and that is the page
    // "converntion-based" :)
    var viewModelName = typeof(T).Name;
    var pageType = typeof(MainView);
    var pageNamespace = pageType.Namespace;
    var pageAssembly = pageType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var newPageName = viewModelName.Substring(0, viewModelName.Length - "Model".Length);
    var newPageType = pageAssembly.GetType($"{pageNamespace}.{newPageName}");

    var newPage = Activator.CreateInstance(newPageType) as Page;
    if (param != null)
        NavigationContext.SetParam(newPage, param);

    var currentPage = ((NavigationPage)App.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage;
    return currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(newPage);
}
```

Make sure to create a binding to property in (DataCapture) view XAML. For example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp" 
    x:Class="SampleApp.DataCaptureView"
    local:NavigationContext.Param="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
```

### Or, option-2. Use virtual method in `BaseViewModel`

Refactor `NavigateTo` to accept a parameter, and update view-model.

```
public static Task NavigateTo<T>(object navigationContext = null)
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    // do some very simple navigation/lookups
    // basically, just remove the "Model" part of the VM and that is the page
    // "converntion-based" :)
    var viewModelName = typeof(T).Name;
    var pageType = typeof(MainView);
    var pageNamespace = pageType.Namespace;
    var pageAssembly = pageType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var newPageName = viewModelName.Substring(0, viewModelName.Length - "Model".Length);
    var newPageType = pageAssembly.GetType($"{pageNamespace}.{newPageName}");
    var newPage = Activator.CreateInstance(newPageType) as Page;

    /* newPage.BindingContext ?? */
    var viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    if (param != null)
        viewModel.SetNavigationContext(navigationContext);
    newPage.BindingContext = viewModel;

    var currentPage = ((NavigationPage)Current.MainPage).CurrentPage;
    return currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(newPage);
}
```

Either reuse `OnAppearing`, or create a method like `SetNavigationContext` in your `BaseViewModel`

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    .....
    public virtual void SetNavigationContext(object context)
    {
    }
```

Override this method in `DataCaptureViewModel`

```
public class DataCaptureViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
...
     public ObservableCollection<Item> SelectedItems { get; set; }
     public override void SetNavigationContext(object context)
     {
          var selectedItems = context as ObservableCollection<Item>;
          SelectedItems = selectedItems;
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of one option over another between option 1 and option 2?

Comment: Also, in first approach, you don't need implement methods for each view-model to accept navigation-context based parameters (properties). Every time, you want to populate a VM property through navigation - you can simply add the binding in View.